# Setting environment variables to an empty string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable, in PowerShell, to an empty string. Note that I don't want to *unset* the environment variable; I want it set but empty. However, PowerShell removes the environment variable entirely if you just set it to the empty string. I've tried the following:

```
$ENV:VAR=''
$ENV:VAR=[String]::Empty
$ENV:VAR=[NullString]::Value
$ENV:VAR=$null
New-Item -Path ENV:VAR -Value ''
New-Item -Path ENV:VAR -Value [string::Empty]
```

Each of those (except the last one) caused the variable not to appear in the output of `Get-ChildItem -path ENV:`. The last one set the environment variable to the literal string `[string::Empty]`, which is definitely not what I wanted.

For completeness:

> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
>
> ```
> Major  Minor  Build  Revision
> -----  -----  -----  --------
> 5      0      10586  117
> ```

I can see that it's *possible* to have an empty environment variable, because I have several:

```
ConEmuANSI                     ON
ConEmuAnsiLog
ConEmuArgs
ConEmuArgs2
ConEmuBackHWND                 0x00F40BFC
```

---

Just for reference, I'm actually trying to set the `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` environment variable to an empty string, because docker-compose treats the absence of that variable as indicating that I want to do TLS verification, and the Docker host I'm using has TLS disabled. I've temporarily given up and switched shells.

Comment: What problem does this solve (why is it needed)?

Comment: Not sure what Docker will make of it, but you can set it to an 'empty' string by setting it to a non-printing character.  For example, a 'tab':  `Set-Item -Path ENV:VAR -Value "\`t"`

Comment: @boxdog that just confuses Docker, unfortunately:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be provided through the client_config param. TLS configurations should map the Docker CLI client configurations. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/ for API details.

Thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: Try This: [String[]]$ENV:VAR = $Null or [String[]]$ENV:VAR = ""

Comment: Also, have you just tried setting DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = $False

Comment: @NickW. [String[]]$ENV:VAR = $Null and [String[]]$ENV:VAR = "" didn't work. DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = $False just confuses Docker (although I blame docker-compose for that).

Comment: An environment variable with a null value should be equivalent to removing the variable. I would consider those `ConEmu` variables to be erroneous (if they really are set to null strings; they shouldn't be).

Answer (score 3):

I have found the same problem. It seems that there is a special behaviour of environment variable that they are deleted by setting them to a blank string.

This works to set a local variable to a blank string:

```
$p = [string]$null
$p.getType()
```

However if you try the same thing using an environment variable, it won't work:

```
$Env:p = [string]$null
$Env:p.getType()
```

According to this web site (https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html) setting an environment variable to a blank string is the prescribed way to delete it.

I think this might be behaviour inherited from the old DOS way of doing environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the following post on another site. From what it says, Docker ignores the value `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` and uses its presence itself as a sort of a on/off switch. If you have it in your script, it's turned on, and if you remove it, DLS is disabled.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22411